# Kafka Streams write an event back to the input topic

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

in my kafka streams app, I need to re-try processing a message whenever a particular type of exception is thrown in the processing logic.

Rather than wrapping my logic in the `RetryTemplate` (am using springboot), am considering just simply writing the message back into the input topic, my assumption is that this message will be added to the back of the log in the appropriate partition and it will eventually be re-processed.

Am aware that this would mess up the ordering and am okay with that.

My question is, would kafka streams have an issue when it encounters a message that was supposedly already processed in the past (am assuming kafka streams has a way of marking the messages it has processed especially when exactly is enabled)?

Here is an example of the code am considering for this solution.

```
val branches = streamsBuilder.stream(inputTopicName)
            .mapValues { it -> myServiceObject.executeSomeLogic(it) }
            .branch(
                { _, value -> value is successfulResult() }, // success
                { _, error -> error is errorResult() },  // exception was thrown
            )

branches[0].to(outputTopicName)
branches[1].to(inputTopicName) //write them back to input as a way of retrying
```

Comment: I never worked with Kafka-Streams, but I guess Kafka-Streams works on partition offsets. Whenever you re-produce a message into the same topic, it's content (Key- and Value) will be equal to the original message, but it will get a new offset. However, I would highly recommend to add a retry-counter to the message (or using a kafka-header) to all retry-messages. You never know if for some reason malicious inputs result in failures, which would (without a retry-counter) result in a andless loop

Comment: Thank you i will try this approach